# How to solve the risks in sharing an Amazon S3 pre-signed URL?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ehcache, pre-signed-url

I am developing a Spring-boot REST API application. The following are the use cases

- All REST API endpoints are secured using HTTPS.
- All responses in this application are cached for 30 minutes based on the request.
- One of my REST API response contains AWS S3 pre-signed url.
- This REST API will be consumed by Mobile App

**Issues**

- How to protect the AWS S3 pre-signed url from hackers who can snoop the request and response in mobile app.
- Since I enforced the cache in my spring-boot application, I am not able to expire the pre-signed url before this cache timeout. The cached response containing the pre-signed url will be used until the cache times out. We are planning to make the cache timeout (say 5 minutes) smaller than the pre-signed url timeout (say 7 minutes)

**Questions**

- How to protect AWS S3 pre-signed URL from hackers
- How to handle this cache logic intelligently, because I don't want to re-generate this pre-signed URL often. Especially after evicting cache on list.
- Is there any solution available to maintain this pre-signed url out of this spring-boot application. That is expecting something like other micro-service can handle this pre-signed url and will be used by mobile app directly.

Any response is kindly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Amazon recommends using their Server-Side Encryption with AWS KMS–Managed Keys (SSE-KMS).  Here is a link to a [Amazon blog series](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generating-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls-with-sse-kms-part-2/) on how to accomplish using their aws-sdk for Java.  This is a link to part 2 of 3 in the series.